# Fastest way to split large xml file per tag

Tags: python, xml, large-data, large-files

I would like to split a very large XML file (20 GB) into small XML files using Python based on the first level tag name

This is the source XML file structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
     <Client id="1">
          <Name>"John"</Name>
          ...
     </Client>
     <Client id="2">
          <Name>"Bob"</Name>
          ...
     </Client>
     <ClientAdditionnalInfo id="1">
          <Address> </Address>
          <Number>  </Number>
     </ClientAdditionnalInfo>
     <ClientAdditionnalInfo id="2">
          <Address> </Address>
          <Number>  </Number>
     </ClientAdditionnalInfo>
     ...
     ...
     ...
     <ClientInvoices>
          <InvoiceNumber>text</InvoiceNumber>
          <InvoiceDate>text</InvoiceDate>
     </ClientInvoices>
     ...
     <Client id="3">
          <Name>"Jenny"</Name>
          ...
     </Client>
          ...
          ...
```

I would like to get as many XML files as first level tags (Client.xml, ClientAdditionnalInfo.xml, ClientInvoices.xml, ...).

Client.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Client id="1">
          <Name>"John"</Name>
          ...
     </Client>
     <Client id="2">
          <Name>"Bob"</Name>
          ...
     </Client>
```

The file has more than 525 million lines and I don't have a list of the tags.

This is my code in Python, but it creates a file for each tag (n-level) and it overwrites existing files...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.iterparse('filename.xml', events=('end', ))

for event, elem in tree:
    filename = format(elem.tag + ".xml")
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(b"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
        f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```

What would be the most efficient way to split the large XML file ?

Comment: Are groups of top-level elements with the same name always adjacent, or can they be interleaved?

Comment: The top level elements are not always adjacent, like in my example, they can be interleaved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the groups of top-level elements are always adjacent, and not interleaved, the following XSLT 3.0 streaming transformation will do the job:

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="objects">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="local-name()">
     <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
     </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

**Disclaimer**: in practice the only streaming XSLT 3.0 engine currently available is Saxon-EE, which is my company's product, and is paid-for software.

You have asked for output files that are not well-formed documents because they contain no outermost wrapper element, and that's what my code will deliver. The output will probably be more useful if you add a wrapper element.

It's likely to run at about 1 minute per gigabyte, depending on your hardware.

Comment: That's great! How long has streaming been out? Its something I could have used a decade ago. There must be some kind of cosmic harmonic thing going on here because I bumped into your original XSLT book this morning and was trying to decide whether to keep it. (I did).

Comment: The XSLT 3.0 spec was finished in 2017; the Saxon implementation of streaming came out incrementally between about 2012 and 2019. Streamed grouping was one of the later things to get implemented, and caused me many headaches!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting this output, and I think it's because the elements are not adjacent...
`Writing to file:output/Client.xml
Writing to file:output/ClientAdditionnalInfo.xml
Error in xsl:result-document/@href on line 8 column 63 of template.xsl:
  XTDE1490  Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI:
  file:output/Client.xml
  In template rule with match="objects" on line 6 of template.xsl`

Comment: Probably yes. Try `href="{current-grouping-key()}{position()}.xml`; you'll then get multiple output files for each name, which you can then combine in a second processing phase (perhaps a non-XSLT process).

Comment: Also note, streaming transformations are often useful just for studying the file contents. Try `<xsl:template match="/objects/*"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>`.